# FormOpen Event procedure not triggered with command button, but trigged when switching from design to form view in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have an MS Access database with a set of forms to enter vegetation data for a large monitoring project.  I have one form called `frmTransect` with a button that opens a second form called `frmLPI` which is set up as an unbound main form with a subform called `frmLPIDetail` bound to a sql server database table.  The main form has just two unbound fields, `DataObs` and `DataRec`, both of which are comboboxes.  These two field are set up with an `AfterUpdate` event procedure to populate their corresponding fields in the subform, `Data_observer` and `Data_recorder`.  This works perfectly.  I wanted to have the unbound fields autopopulate with the last value in the subform of `Data_observer` and `Data_recorder` when the form is lauched again.  To do this I used a `FormOpen` event procedure.  Below is the code:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

Me.TransectOID = Me.OpenArgs
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = Me!frmLPIDetail.Form.RecordsetClone

If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then

If Not rs.BOF Then
rs.MoveLast
rs.MovePrevious
End If

If Not IsNull(rs!Data_recorder.Value) Then
        Me.DataRec.Value = rs!Data_recorder.Value
        Me.frmLPIDetail.Form.Data_recorder.DefaultValue = """" & Me.DataRec.Value & """"
End If

If Not IsNull(rs!Data_observer.Value) Then
        Me.DataObs.Value = rs!Data_observer.Value
        Me.frmLPIDetail.Form.Data_observer.DefaultValue = """" & Me.DataObs.Value & """"
End If
        rs.MoveLast
        rs.MoveFirst
    
    While Not rs.EOF
        rs.Edit
        rs!Data_recorder.Value = Me.DataRec.Value
        rs!Data_observer.Value = Me.DataObs.Value
        rs.Update
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend
End If
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Me.Dirty = False
End Sub
```

Here is where things get weird.  When I click the command button on `frmTransect`, `frmLPI` opens, but the `FormOpen` event procedure above doesn't get launched.  However, if I switch into design view, and then back into Form View, it does trigger, and works as intended! How can I get this event procedure to launch when I open the `frmLPI` using the command button in `frmTransect`?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So main form frmLPI is UNBOUND and has two UNBOUND controls (not fields) which are comboboxes? What is TransectOID and why is it populated with OpenArgs? I cannot replicate issue. The main form OnOpen event always fires for me. Edit question to show button code opening form.

Comment: Why does this code set values of recordset fields? What process requires changing data of existing records when form opens? This will likely put multiple simultaneous users in conflict.

Comment: Use the `Form_Load()` event.

Comment: Hi June7, Thanks for catching that.  TransectOID is an UNBOUND field in the main form.  It is the identifier that retrieves the correct records for the LPI form.  I suppose a quick bit of background might elucidate what my form is set up this way.  The vegetation monitoring project consists of 24 sampling sites.  Each site has for lines on which we measure vegetation cover.  In vegetation ecology, these are referred to as "transects."  LPI stands for "Line-Point-Intercept", and is the method by which we measure plant cover.  Continued in next comment.

Comment: On each transect, there are 30 points where we shine a laser beam and record every plant the beam hits.   In my access database frmLPI captures the metadata for the transect (its unique ID which is TransectOID) and the data recorder and data observer.  I have a sql table prepopulated with all 30 records for each transect and TransectOID is the link field between frmLPI and frmLPIDetail.  I have the loop set up to populate each row with data_observer and data_recorder so my coworkers who will be entering the data don't have to enter those values more than once.

Comment: I set up my code to change existing field to ensure that the unbound `DataObs` and `DataRec` fields in `frmLPI` always match their counterparts in `frmLPIDetail`.  I have used the same code successful with the intended behavior and no write conflicts in other forms.  In this form it does work as intended when switching between design view and form view, but not when I click the command button in `frmTransect` Here is the code I use for the`OnClick` event that opens `frmLPI` from `frmTransect`: `Private Sub btnLPI_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmLPI", OpenArgs:=Me.Transect_OID
End Sub`

Comment: Kostas K, I had that same thought, but when I tried switching to the `Form_Load` event I had the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And it turned out it was as simple as adding a `Me.Refresh` and `Me.Requery` to my code block:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

Me.TransectOID = Me.OpenArgs
Me.Refresh
Me.Requery

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = Me!frmLPIDetail.Form.RecordsetClone

If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then

rs.MoveLast
rs.MovePrevious

If Not IsNull(rs!Data_recorder.Value) Then
        Me.DataRec.Value = rs!Data_recorder.Value
        Me.frmLPIDetail.Form.Data_recorder.DefaultValue = """" & Me.DataRec.Value & """"
End If

If Not IsNull(rs!Data_observer.Value) Then
        Me.DataObs.Value = rs!Data_observer.Value
        Me.frmLPIDetail.Form.Data_observer.DefaultValue = """" & Me.DataObs.Value & """"
End If
        rs.MoveLast
        rs.MoveFirst
End If
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Me.Dirty = False

End Sub
```